# Sum of two affine connections

Tags: differential-geometry

I wanted to define some tensor like this 
\begin{align}
\phi(X,Y,Z)=g(\nabla^\Sigma_XY,Z),
\end{align}
where $\nabla^\Sigma$ is equal to the sum of two known connections.
Is the sum of two affine connections again an affine connection, or it is just a tensor?
Does my definition make sense?

Comment: Why do you suspect that a sum of affine connections is *either* an affine connection *or* "just" a tensor? Affine connections are not tensors, and they form an affine vector space, not a vector space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some definitions/corollaries which may clarify things somewhat.

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, and let $C^\infty M$ be the space of smooth real valued functions on $M$ and $\mathfrak{X}M$ and $\mathfrak{X}^*M$ be the spaces of smooth vector fields and covector fields respectively. Let $F:\mathfrak{X}M\times\mathfrak{X}M\times\mathfrak{X}^*M\to C^\infty M$ be a function. We say that $F$:

♦ *is $\mathbb{R}$-linear in its first argument* if $F(aX_1+bX_2,Y,\omega)=aF(X_1,Y,\omega)+bF(X_2,Y,\omega)$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ (and likewise for other arguments)

♦ *is $C^\infty$-linear in its first argument* if $F(fX_1+gX_2,Y,\omega)=fF(X_1,Y,\omega)+gF(X_2,Y,\omega)$ for $f,g\in C^\infty M$ (and likewise for other arguments)

♦ *obeys the product rule for affine connections* if $F(X,fY,\omega)=fF(X,Y,\omega)+(Xf)\langle Y,\omega\rangle$ for $f\in C^\infty M$ (where $Xf$ denotes the derivative of $f$ along $X$ and $\langle\ \ ,\ \rangle$ denotes the natural pairing of vectors and covectors)

For convenience, I'll regard an affine connection as a function of two vector fields and a covector field $\nabla(X,Y,\omega)\equiv\langle\nabla_X Y,\omega\rangle$. This form encodes the same information, and is equivalent to what you've written if you lower the third argument with the metric. Using a covector for the third argument is a bit more standard, as it eliminates the need for a metric.

Among functions of this form, we're interested in two types.

*Tensors*, (specifically $\binom{2}{1}$ tensors in this case) are $C^\infty$-linear in all arguments.

*Affine connections*, meanwhile, are $C^\infty$-linear in the first and third argument, $\mathbb{R}$-linear in the second argument, and obey the product rule.

A few important facts relate these two types of maps:

1. Affine connections are never $\binom{2}{1}$ tensors.
2. Any linear combination of functions $C^\infty$-linear in a particular argument remains $C^\infty$-linear in that argument (and likewise with $\mathbb{R}$-linearity). In particular, any linear combination of $\binom{2}{1}$ tensors is a $\binom{2}{1}$ tensor.
3. The difference of two affine connections is a $\binom{2}{1}$ tensor. More generally, a linear combination $\Gamma=\sum_i a_i\nabla_i,\ \ a_i\in\mathbb{R}$ is a tensor if and only if $\sum_i a_i=0$.
4. A linear combination of affine connections $\nabla^\Sigma=\sum_i a_i\nabla_i,\ \ a_i\in\mathbb{R}$ is an affine connection if and only if $\sum_i a_i=1$.

These properties come up a lot in the study of affine connections. Checking them is a matter of determining if the defining rules are satisfied.

Comment: Thank you very much!